# start Chromium automatically after boot on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, chromium, rc

I have a Linux setup attached to an HDMI cable and I want to start Chromium automatically after boot (before login)

I tried modifying the `rc.local` file, adding:

```
/usr/bin/chromium --no-sandbox --touch-events=enabled --kiosk http://192.168.1.2:8080 &
```

but it doesn't work, Chromium doesn't start.
I tried replacing that line with

```
touch /test
```

And I see the file being created on `/`, so the `rc.local` file is actually working

The chromium command line works perfectly from the console

**EDIT**

I use the xdg desktop interface. Linux is a Yocto build

Comment: Which Linux OS are you using?

Comment: @AlfredE.Noobman please check my edit

Comment: What is the full path to `rc.local`? Are you using `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/init.d/rc.local`?

Comment: could it be that x-system has not been started yet? you could wait 10 seconds before chromium starts, e.g. ```sleep 10 && /usr/bin/chromium ...```.

Comment: it is better to let the window managers handle auto starting of a GUI application.